# Solve and Simplify

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

MMA version 12.3 Windows

Has anybody an explanation why "Solve" gives different results if you use "Simplify" on the argument or not.

Here we create 3 equations (it does not matter how they are created):

```
d = Table[Append[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3}], 1], 3];
pl = Cross @@ d;
pt = {x, y, z, 1};
eq1 = pl . pt == 0;
eq2 = ( ((# - pt) . (# - pt)) & /@ d );
eq = {eq1, eq2[[1]] == eq2[[2]], eq2[[2]] == eq2[[3]]};
```

If I solve this, I get:

```
sol= Solve[eq, {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

This is not a full solution, x is still free and it does not solve the first equation for arbitrary x. E.g.:

```
eq /. sol /. x -> 1
(* {False, True, True} *)
```

However if I simplify the equations I get the full correct solution:

```
eq = eq // Simplify;
sol=Solve[eq, {x, y, z}][[1]]

eq /. sol
(* {True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: First, `Solve` also produces a warning "Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables." Second,  `Solve` may use nonequivalent transformations. Third, use `Reduce` instead of `Solve`. Last, but not least: your code is irreproducible because you use `RandomReal` without `Block`.

Comment: I used "RandomReal" on purpose to show that the error does not depend on a special input. But the point is Solve returns a WRONG result!

Answer (score 4):

Well, Solve does not do `Simplify` on its input automatically.  It will not be a good idea for `Solve` to simplify its input automatically.

When you did simplify, the expression changed just enough to make it give the full answer you saw. (may be due to numerical rounding or cancellation and such, since the input is not exact)

The warning says this basically

> Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact
> coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact
> system and numericizing the result.

One way to get same answer as the one you obtained using `Simplify` but without using `Simplify` is to convert the input to exact before calling `Solve`

```
eqGood = SetPrecision[eq, Infinity];
sol = Solve[eqGood, {x, y, z}] // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to

```
sol = Solve[Simplify@eq, {x, y, z}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Solve` is really meant for exact input. Why not just use `NSolve`? This way, you'll get all the solutions, without simplify and without having to convert input to exact:

```
 sol = NSolve[eq, {x, y, z}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank's a lot, your hints are appreciated, but that does not explain why Solve gives a wrong result.

Answer (score 4):

```
SeedRandom[1234];

d = Table[Append[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3}], 1], 3];
pl = Cross @@ d;
pt = {x, y, z, 1};
eq1 = pl . pt == 0;
eq2 = (((# - pt) . (# - pt)) & /@ d);
eq = {eq1, eq2[[1]] == eq2[[2]], eq2[[2]] == eq2[[3]]};
```

[`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) is an exact solver and should be given exact input.

```
sol = Solve[eq // Rationalize[#, 0] &, {x, y, z}] // N

(* {{x -> 0.952153, y -> -0.786618, z -> 0.232846}} *)

eq /. sol[[1]]

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

Or, for inexact input use [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)

```
solN = NSolve[eq, {x, y, z}]

(* {{x -> 0.952153, y -> -0.786618, z -> 0.232846}} *)

eq /. solN[[1]]

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Solve` without simplification of `eq` produces an unfinished work, but a correct result. Here are my arguments.
Let us execute (`BlockRandom` guarantees this is reproducible.)

```
d= BlockRandom[Table[Append[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3}], 1], 3]];
pl = Cross @@ d;pt = {x, y, z, 1};eq1 = pl . pt == 0;
eq2 = (((# - pt) . (# - pt)) & /@ d);
eq = {eq1, eq2[[1]] == eq2[[2]], eq2[[2]] == eq2[[3]]}
sol = Solve[eq, {x, y, z}]
```

> `{{y -> 0.442888 - 0.456132 x, z -> 0.0787157 - 0.00412639 x}}`

and a warning "Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.". Next,

```
Simplify[eq /. %[[1]]]
```

> `{1. x == 0.602777, True, True}`

At last,

```
Solve[{1. x == 0.602777, True, True}, {x}, Reals]
```

> `{{x -> 0.602777}}`

Compare

```
eq
```

> `0.324732 - 0.617528 x + 0.281674 y + 0.00254816 z ==  0, (0.464599 - x)^2 + (-0.130691 - y)^2 + (-0.399105 -  z)^2 == (0.810494 - x)^2 + (0.62591 - y)^2 + (-0.208966 -  z)^2, (0.810494 - x)^2 + (0.62591 - y)^2 + (-0.208966 -  z)^2 == (0.399552 - x)^2 + (-0.280342 - y)^2 + (0.379474 - z)^2}`

with

```
Simplify[eq]
```

> `{1. x == 0.525859 + 0.456132 y + 0.00412639 z, 1. x + 2.18737 y + 0.549701 z == 1.01203, 1. x + 2.2053 y == 0.863986 + 1.43193 z}`

Hope this explains the problem.

Comment: @user644943 Thanks for pointing out that the result is unfinished. I do not think that is acceptable for a not too cheap software. that is otherwise great

Comment: @DanielHuber: Every command has its limitations. I have demonstrated `Solve` produces a correct result contrary your claim "Solve returns a WRONG result".

Comment: Sorry, I do not agree. The statement: `{y -> 0.442888 - 0.456132 x, z -> 0.0787157 - 0.00412639 x}` say that the equations are fulfilled for any value of of x. And this is obviously not the case.

Comment: @DanielHuber: You don't take into account a warning "Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables." to this result.